# NOT_AUTHORIZED error – only in PayPal Live environment

Tags: node.js, express, rest, paypal

I'm building a marketplace and trying to integrate PayPal into it. I want users to connect their PayPal accounts to the platform. I got it all working in the Sandbox environment (the whole integration). But, as soon as I switch to Live it throws the following error:

```
data: {
  name: 'NOT_AUTHORIZED',
  message: 'Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.',
  debug_id: 'f4c87859c9f90',
  information_link: '',
  details: [Array],
  links: []
}
```

The endpoint that I call to get this error is: `https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals`

No other details. Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a live partner app to use the referrals API.

As the [note in the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/create-account/) says:

> [Fill out this form](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/#link-tellusaboutyourplatform) to be an approved partner. You need to be an
> approved partner to go live. Calls to the PayPal Commerce Platform
> APIs without approval will return a 401 Unauthorized HTTP status code.
> You can call and test the PayPal Commerce Platform APIs with your
> sandbox credentials before you are approved.

Comment: I've filled out this form 4 times already and no one ever contacts me...

Comment: Unfortunately that's the rough equivalent of a "no"